# Perl command dbmopen not working

Tags: perl

we have snippet like below,

**dbmopen(%NEWHASHTABLE, "$hashFile", $mode);**

where hash file is like below

1:- D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/local/config/PublicWeb/modules/ModuleLightingECatalogueSection--publicweb_lighting--main--shared--STAGING.db

2:- D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/local/config/PublicWeb/modules/ModuleLightingECatalogueSection--publicweb_lighting--main--webdevelopment--WORKAREA--w-main.db

and mode is 666.

When I tried fetching out data out of hash table (%NEWHASHTABLE) , I found no data in it.

Can you please suggest what can be added ?

And the same code is working in our old teamsite version but in the new version it doesn't.

Comment: Here is the snppet of my code :- $hashFile = "D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/local/config/PublicWeb/modules/ModuleLightingECatalogueSection--publicweb_lighting--main--webdevelopment--WORKAREA--w-main.db";
&readHash;
sub readHash {
dbmopen(%NEWHASHTABLE, "$hashFile", $mode) or die  print "Can't open : $!";
#Added below to check size of hash table 
          
my @values = values %NEWHASHTABLE;
my $size = @values;
print LOG "Size of hash table:  is $size\n"; 
 %MODULE_HASHTABLE = %NEWHASHTABLE;
 dbmclose(%NEWHASHTABLE);
}

Comment: I am seeing hash table size as zero.

Comment: Please add the code snippet to the body of the quesiton. if you indent the lines by five space, it will be formatted at a code block.

Comment: How do I include a DB_File module? Is it necessary to install any module for this?
We tried adding DB_File.pm manually under the "lib" folder. Are we missing something here?
We are getting the below error after the manual addition.
Root cause:
Can't locate loadable object for module DB_File in @INC (@INC contains: D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/iw-perl/lib D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/iw-perl/site/lib D:\Interwoven\TeamSite\iw-perl\vendor\lib .) at D:\Interwoven\TeamSite\local\bin\PhilipsPubWebGetModuleFiles.ipl line 22 Compilation failed in require at

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet should include error checking.
You are checking for errors, right?

```
 dbmopen(%NEWHASHTABLE, "$hashFile", $mode) or die "Can't open $hashfile: $!";
```

If you haven't checked for errors, and you aren't running with strictures (`use strict`) enabled, then you'll have an empty hash after `dbmopen` fails.

`--------------- 2014-10-31 Updates-------------------------`

I do not see a `use DB_File` in your code snippet, so then given that Perl is going to assume that the [file name you provided is the name of the dbm file (without the .pag or .dir extensions)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html), your program is trying to open D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/local/config/PublicWeb/modules/ModuleLightingECatalogueS..ection--publicweb_lighting--main--webdevelopment--WORKAREA--w-main.db.pag

So first of all, we need to know which flavor of DBM file you're trying to work with.
It will be helpfull to run the [file(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command on your DBM file and report what it says.

Comment: Thanks for heads up on this. We are trying to populate some dropdown options using dbmopen. When I checked the hash table it is having nothing inside it but when the same code ran on 32 bit it is giving options as expected. Do you think any environment variables need to be passed explicitly ? or any other suggestions ?

Comment: You did not answer my question about checking errors. There are uncountable reasons why your code is not working, but the simplest thing to do is check the `dbmopen()` call for errors and report them.

Comment: I don't see any error in the log when I used your suggested code to check error and we are having strictures (use strict) enabled in our code.

Comment: How do I include a DB_File module? Is it necessary to install any module for this?  We tried adding DB_File.pm manually under the "lib" folder. Are we missing something here? We are getting the below error after the manual addition.  Root cause: Can't locate loadable object for module DB_File in @INC (@INC contains: D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/iw-perl/lib D:/Interwoven/TeamSite/iw-perl/site/lib D:\Interwoven\TeamSite\iw-perl\vendor\lib .) at D:\Interwoven\TeamSite\local\bin\PhilipsPubWebGetModuleFiles.ipl line 22 Compilation failed